# Facebook v1.0 app and v2.0 behavior

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an old v1.0 app that I am trying to use to collect data for my friends before the April 30th migration deadline. When I log into the app, the /me/friends route returns all of my friends as expected, but when my friend logs in, the /me/friends route only returns myself, but not in the v2.0 { data: [], summary: { total_count: 570 } } format.
The app was created before April 30th, 2014.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: In v2.0 and later /me/friends just return friends that have granted user_friends. And the user them self also need to grant the app user_friends

Comment: Yes I know, but my point is that my app IS v1.0. It returns all of my friends when I log in, but only me when my friend logs in. If I create a new fb app, when I log in I do not get any of my friends, just the count. Why would identical code display v1.0 behavior for me, but v2.0 behavior for my friends? I am hoping there is somewhere out there that can account for this strangeness.

Comment: If the user logged in using v1.0 you will get v1.0 behavior on /me/friends. If the user logged in using v2.0 you will get v2.0 behavior on /me/friends

Comment: This is apparently not true, or at least there is an edge case. I was logging in with the v2.0 API the whole time apparently. But /me/friends was still returning all of my friends. However /me/friends would only return myself when my friend logged in. Hence my confusion.

Comment: It is what login you used the first time. I assume you logged in using v1.0 the first time you logged into the app

Comment: No I was logging in using v2.0 the entire time. The passport.js library I was using to login was auto prefixing /v2.0/ to all requests going to FB. That was the problem, I stopped using passport and all routes for all users are now displaying v1.0 behavior.

Comment: You said it was a v1.0 app? You saying you never logged in to the app before you changed everything to v2.0?

Comment: That is correct. I created the app over 2 years ago and logged in for the first time just a couple of weeks ago using passport.js

Comment: You must have logged in over 2 years ago then. Otherwise there is a bug and you should file one at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs.

Comment: I was actually thinking about doing that. Because you are right, it is either undocumented behavior, or a bug. But it doesn't really matter anymore since v1.0 will be deprecated entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you're the app admin, and your friend isn't... But I'm not aware that this is documented somewhere.

Try to prefix the Graph API calls with `/v2.0` (also the OAuth calls), and see if this changes something.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_login
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_api_versions
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_login (see chapter "Friend Interactions Between v1.0 and v2.0 Logins")

Comment: Your answer led me to discover the solution. The passport.js library was auto prefixing v2.0 to all the facebook API calls. I still find it strange though that even while using v2.0 I was still able to get all of my friends. Perhaps it is some undocumented behavior like you suggested. Either way, thanks!